# JNI: Can not get array length

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I faced with the next problem: I can not do anything with `byte[] (jbyteArray)` in C code. All functions that work with array in JNI cause `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray argument has non-array type`. What's wrong with my code?

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

static jstring convertToHex(JNIEnv* env, jbyteArray array) {
    int len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);// cause an error;
    return NULL;
}

static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"convertToHex", "([B)Ljava/lang/String;", (void*) convertToHex },
};

JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;

    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/infomir/stalkertv/server/ServerUtil");

    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls, methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]) );

    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

ServerUtil:

```
public class ServerUtil {

    public ServerUtil() {
        System.loadLibrary("shadow");
    }

    public native String convertToHex(byte[] array);
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ServerUtil serverUtil = new ServerUtil();
        byte[] a = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        String s = serverUtil.convertToHex(a);
    }
}
```

My environment:

- Android Studio 2.0
- Experimental Gradle plugin 0.7.0
- JAVA 1.8
- NDK r11b
- Windows 10 x64

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument passed to your function **isn't** a `jbyteArray`.

Per the [JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html), the arguments passed to a native function are:

> **Native Method Arguments**
>
> The JNI interface pointer is the first argument to native methods. The
>   JNI interface pointer is of type JNIEnv. **The second argument differs
>   depending on whether the native method is static or nonstatic. The
>   second argument to a nonstatic native method is a reference to the
>   object. The second argument to a static native method is a reference
>   to its Java class.**
>
> The remaining arguments correspond to regular Java method arguments.
>   The native method call passes its result back to the calling routine
>   via the return value.

Your `jstring convertToHex(JNIEnv* env, jbyteArray array)` is missing the second `jclass` or `jobject` argument, so you're treating either a `jobject` or `jclass` argument and a `jbyteArray`.

Answer (score 3):

Your native method signature is incorrect. It should be

```
static jstring convertToHe(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbytearray array)
```