# Why Is JNA Not Mapping char** to String[]?

Tags: java, jna

I'm attempting to link a java program to a dll using JNA.

In my C++ DLL I have a function that takes in a `char**`. The [JNA API](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/overview-summary.html#marshalling) implies that should be mapped to `String[]` in Java.

So as far as I'm aware `Foo(..., char** bar, ...)` should become `native Foo(..., String[] bar, ...)`. However when I attempt to run the program I get an exception.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class [Ljava.lang.String; is not a supported argument type (in method Foo in class DLL)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1604)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1529)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1252)
    at DLL.<clinit>(TrajParser.java:28)
```

If I change the signature on the java side to be `byte[]` or `PointerByReference` it *does* seem to allow the program to start, but I'm not sure how to convert my `String[]` into either of those types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out rather than using `String[]` you can instead create a `com.sun.jna.StringArray`

so it becomes `native Foo(..., StringArray bar, ...)` and to call the function you just wrap a `String[]`:

```
String[] array = new String[n];

DLL.Foo(..., new StringArray(array), ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that JNI/JNA uses primitive types. String instance are Objects not primitive(even if the classe is in the java.lang package) , so have an in Memory Java representation that is not compatible with C Code. For info, the representation of this object stores a kind of structure with: a reference to the class (String) a reference to the internal array representation, then the array have it's own in memory representation too.

Your option is to convert Strings from/to bytes, you need to use a Charset:

to send a String

```
"My string".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

to receive

```
new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way of passing a string array into the dll, as jna does not allow for two dimensional arrays? As `String[]` would have to boil down to `byte[][]`, right?

Comment: For 2 dimentionnal array, You will need to use JNIEnv like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082509/jni-can-not-get-array-length https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751825/simplest-way-to-pass-float-to-c-via-jni Sorry I have no fully working example